# Creating tool for metadata standard for spatial data?

Tags: metadata, software-recommendations, standards

I am looking to develop a tool to make cadastral metadata in a particular scenario.

I would keep the ISO standards for meta in view of my development.

Any suggestions in creating the tool for Metadata?

Comment: which software do you use ?

Comment: I am looking for the tool/platform/software to develop standards,,

Answer (score 1):

My best tip for you is to keep it simple. After messing around with Metadata standards for nearly 5 years (and no end in sight) a colleague of mine and I decided that its a good idea to throw all these standards over board and just document the things we need in a database. Open Data let us rethink the whole standardization theme, which really became just to complicated over the couple of years. Just choose the one editor in ArcCatalog that best fits your needs for documentation and information exchange.

This version of the [ArcGIS Metadata Toolkit](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/samples-and-utilities/view/productid/160/metaid/1937) provides tools and documentation that let you create and share custom metadata styles that use the validation capabilities provided in the ArcGIS metadata editor with ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 SP1.

[A quick tour of creating and editing metadata](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003t00000007000000)

[Upgrading existing FGDC metadata from the Description tab](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Upgrading_existing_FGDC_metadata_from_the_Description_tab/003t00000024000000/)